# How to send a list of objects from Flask to React

Tags: python, json, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I know similar questions have been asked and answered before but somehow none of those solutions worked for me. I have the following query:

```
results = (
   db.session(TestInfo.test, TestInfo.test_regime_name, StandardResult.cell_id)
   .select_from(TestInfo)
   .join(StandardResult, TestInfo.test==StandardResult.test)
   .distinct(StandardResult.cell_id)
   .all()
)
```

Since the data comes from a machine, there are no relationships between the tables and I have to manually join the two tables. This returns a list of tuples that doesn't include the object keys (column names). So, to include those, I used the following logic:

```
response = [row._mapping for row in results]
```

This then returns a list of objects that looks like:

```
[{'test': '2514', 'test_regime_name': '4695 XX XXX', 'cell_id': '000123456'}, {...}, {...}, ...]
```

Now, I am struggling to convert this into JSON so it can be served to the React frontend.

Comment: just return response or you can use jsonify from flask, its similar `json.dumps(response)`

Comment: Returning this response directly or via jsonify throws an error `TypeError(f"Object of type {type(o}.__name__} is not JSON serializable")`

Already tried that

Answer (score 0):

Ok it's a bit annoying that this whole time I was trying to do the same and it didn't work and now suddenly it works. Here's what worked for me:

Converted `row._mapping` into a dictionary and then returned it via jsonify

```
response = [dict(row._mapping) for row in results]

return jsonify(response)
```